# Getting the request origin in a Django request

Tags: python, django, post, cross-domain

So I'm trying to enable cross origin resource sharing in Django, so I can post to an external site, and it's easy to do when I set

```
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]="*"
```

but I want to instead have it check whether the origin is in an allowed list of origins (essentially to restrict it to only allow specific sites) but I can't seem to find anywhere in the Django request where I can get the origin information.

I tried using **request.META['HTTP_HOST']** but that just returns the site that's being posted to. Does anyone know where in the Request object I can get the origin of the request?

Comment: You can find how to set this up for Django overall or for specific endpoints/views in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355540/access-control-allow-origin-in-django-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly advice you to use [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers). It lets you to define `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` which is a list of allowed origins in more pythonic way.

Answer (score 31):

As for getting the url from `request` (which is what I was looking for), use `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` instead.

Comment: this returns a KeyError

Comment: What version of Django are you using? What do you get if you print `request.META.keys()`? Here's the documentation on the request meta: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: @ZAD-Man its possible he is experiencing KeyError from django tests, in which case there's no HTTP_REFERER. Anyway I'm not sure, but I think he should use REMOTE_HOST for what he want to get.

Comment: @Ness - Ah, OK, I could see that.

Comment: Since the 1.9 docs are no longer up, the current equivalent of my first comment's link is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Note that you can just change the version in the URL to the current version, in case 4.2 is taken down in the future.

Answer (score 11):

In Django,

```
request.headers['Origin']
```

answers the original question.

You can `print(request.headers)` to see everything available in the headers.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
origin = request.META.get("HTTP_ORIGIN")
```

This is the way `django-cors-headers` use it in the [middleware](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/blob/17fdac51e77e3c883b384bb5dec6b48effe4c705/src/corsheaders/middleware.py#L56):

Answer (score 2):

you can get it by request.META["HTTP_ORIGIN"]

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "Does anyone know where in the Request object I can get the origin of the request?", would the request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] give you what you need?

Comment: Does not work, it gives an IP address, not an host name.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.2 use:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

Make sure that the request property doesn't have mode = no-cors

see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

"There are some exceptions to the above rules; for example, if a cross-origin GET or HEAD request is made in no-cors mode, the Origin header will not be added."

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes HTTP_REFERER may not contain a value ?