# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Django app

Tags: python, ajax, django, cordova, cors

I'm developing a Phonegap app for my Django based app, but when trying to make Ajax calls I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.herokuapp.com/getcsrf/?tags=jquery%2Cjavascript&tagmode=any&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can I make it so my Django app allows cross origin for some urls?

Here's my Ajax code:

```
get: function() {
    $.getJSON("http://domain.herokuapp.com/getcsrf/",
    {
        tags: "jquery,javascript",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(item){
            console.log(item);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Have never used Django, but did you add the server to your cordova/phonegap whitelist?

Comment: How do you do that? Didn't know you could add a server whitelist to cordova/phonegap app

Comment: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: in my config.xml I had the default `<access origin="*" />` already

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Django by default does not provide the headers necessary to provide cross origin. The easiest way would be to just use this Django app that handles it for you: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers

- Add to installed apps
- Add to middleware
- Then stuff like...

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://read.only.com",
    "http://change.allowed.com",
]
```

to support allowing all, just use the setting...
`CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`
and then do any filtering of the request in middleware or in the view.

Comment: Ok, already installed it, but doesn't seem to change, maybe because I want to allow 3 urls (any tip or best practise using django-cors-heades?)

Comment: I updated the example to show how to add domains/urls to the whitelist.

Comment: Cordova/Phonegaps apps run by file:// location and does not have domain so how to list them in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST =() ?

Comment: `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` and then do any filtering of the request in middleware or in the view.

Comment: For people using Django 1.10 or later, use this: https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware. The original link doesn't support 1.10.

Comment: Thank you so much Guilherme Santos, for the link to new repository.

Comment: The original repo seems to support Django 2, unlike the other one

Comment: When using django-cors-headers it may be preferable to add 'null' (string) to CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST. i.e. CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('null',...) which may resolve the issue and avoids disabling CORS completely. From the docs: "The value 'null' can also appear in this list, and will match the Origin: null header that is used in "privacy-sensitive contexts", such as when the client is running from a file:// domain."

Comment: The setting was renamed to `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`

Comment: Good answer, but does not mention that you need to add the cors headers app and middleware in your django project settings, I've added a more detailed answer since the edit queue is full: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67844932/10307728

Answer (score 33):

For single views you can manually add headers:

```
@require_GET
def api_getto(request):
    response = JsonResponse(
        # your stuff here
    )
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, OPTIONS"
    response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, Content-Type"
    return response
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use "django-cors-headers". Simply install it using pip:

```
    pip install django-cors-headers
```

Add 'corsheaders' to your installed apps:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
        'corsheaders',
        ...
    ]
```

Add middleware:

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        ...,
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        ...,
    ]
```

Then add this to your "settings.py":

```
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
        'http://siteyouwantto.allow.com',
        'http://anothersite.allow.com',
    ]
```

If you also want to allow some domains to make "POST" requests, add this to your "settings.py" and don't forget to add it in "CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS".

```
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
        'http://siteyouwantto.allow.com',
    ]
```

I hope this resolves your issue :)

Comment: You'll also need to add the cors headers app and middleware in your settings, see [the README](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#configuration) or [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67844932/10307728)

Comment: @orangecaterpillar you are right ! I will edit my answer :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use **django-cors-headers** as others have suggested, as of writing this you'll need to follow all the steps below.

To use **django-cors-headers** in your project, follow the guide in the **Setup** and **Configuration** sections of [the cors headers project's README](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#setup), or read it below (I've copied from the README for convenience).

---

### [SETUP](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#setup)

Install from pip:

`python -m pip install django-cors-headers`

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

Make sure you add the trailing comma or you might get a ModuleNotFoundError (see [this blog post](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/06/29/why-does-python-raise-modulenotfounderror-when-modifying-installed-apps/)).

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...,
]
```

`CorsMiddleware` should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's `CommonMiddleware` or Whitenoise's `WhiteNoiseMiddleware`. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses.

Also if you are using `CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER` it should be placed before Django's `CsrfViewMiddleware`.

---

### [CONFIGURATION](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#configuration)

Configure the middleware's behaviour in your Django settings. You must set at least one of three following settings:

```
`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`
`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES`
`CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS`
```

#### `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`

A list of origins that are authorized to make cross-site HTTP requests. Defaults to `[]`.

An Origin is defined by [the CORS RFC Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-3.2) as a URI scheme + hostname + port, or one of the special values 'null' or 'file://'. Default ports (HTTPS = 443, HTTP = 80) are optional here.

The special value null is sent by the browser in ["privacy-sensitive contexts"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-6), such as when the client is running from a file:// domain. The special value file:// is sent accidentally by some versions of Chrome on Android as per [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107).

Example:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
]
```

Previously this setting was called `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`, which still works as an alias, with the new name taking precedence.

#### `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES`

A list of strings representing regexes that match Origins that are authorized to make cross-site HTTP requests. Defaults to `[]`. Useful when `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` is impractical, such as when you have a large number of subdomains.

Example:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"^https://\w+\.example\.com$",
]
```

Previously this setting was called `CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST`, which still works as an alias, with the new name taking precedence.

#### `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS`

If `True`, all origins will be allowed. Other settings restricting allowed origins will be ignored. Defaults to `False`.

Setting this to `True` can be dangerous, as it allows any website to make cross-origin requests to yours. Generally you'll want to restrict the list of allowed origins with `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` or `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES`.

Previously this setting was called `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL`, which still works as an alias, with the new name taking precedence.

Comment: Note that it appears that there is a missing/broken link in this clause: "Make sure you add the trailing comma or you might get a ModuleNotFoundError (see this blog post)."

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was posting a file more than 1 mb and I was getting this error because of `nginx` configration (default max size 1 mb) So......

For me path of `nginx.conf` was `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

In my case I just added `client_max_body_size` in `http block` and it worked for me

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 200M;
}
```

Make sure to restart nginx after changing this config

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add the documentation here:

> CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before
> any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's
> CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise's WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not
> before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these
> responses.

from this link https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers

If your cors middleware is not top of the django middleware list, the above answers may not work