# POST fails without executing even a single line

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to POST from a website with different origin. I use JavaScript to call the API.

A minimal example of what I've done is shown:

**JavaScript**:

```
options = {method: 'POST',
      // mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: formData
    }
    fetch(url, options).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    });
  }
```

**Django Rest Framework based class**:

```
class ImageUpload(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("data:", request.data)
        print("file:", request.FILES)

        response = Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
        print(response)
        return response

    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = Response()
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
        print(response)
        return response
```

With this example, I get CORS error that Cross-Origin Request is Blocked. This is due to the missing header. Interestingly, upon calling the API, my django console doesn't print a single line which it was supposed to upon calling the POST request. How did DRF send a response without going into `def post`? Before calling POST, OPTIONS is called which behaves perfectly as it should have. I even got the response printed on console.

Also, another observation is, the API works perfectly fine when i uncomment `mode: 'no-cors'`.

Upon researching, I found that I can use [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers), but opening up CORS to all the views of the entire project seems to be an overkill. As per the [documentation of DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#standard-httpresponse-attributes) and as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50752124), I should have been correctly using the headers, but that would be the case, if I would atleast enter the `post` function defined in the class.

Can someone point out what is going on here and where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who lands up to this question, found that `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},` is causing the errors. I'm not sure why, but removing this solved the issue. If someone can try to explain this, would be a lot helpful :)