# store UUID in session using middleware

Tags: django, django-sessions

I want to tag all requests with a UUID
(if the request doesn't have it in the first place).

I want to store the UUID in the session, so I wrote this middleware.

```py
class MachineIDMiddleware:
    """
    tags requests with machine UUIDs.
    The machine-ID is set in the session.
    """

    MID_KEY = "machine_id"

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        print(request.session.get(self.MID_KEY))
        if self.MID_KEY not in request.session:
            # set the machine-ID for the request
            # if it has not been set already (making
            # sure that it is serializable).
            next_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            request.session[self.MID_KEY] = next_id
        return self.get_response(request)
```

However, from my client, I noticed that the UUID keeps changing for every request.
From my client, I noticed that the `sessionid` cookie also changed for every request made.

As a result, a new UUID was generated for every request.
This is not what I want, though. I want to maintain only one UUID per person (who might be anonymous).

How can I achieve this?
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

```js
export const Adapter = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});

Adapter.interceptors.request.use(
  (request) => {
    const token = tokenSelector(store.getState());
    if (token) {
      request.headers.Authorization = `Token ${token}`;
    }
    return request;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

Adapter.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    // handle unauthorized errors.
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch(clearToken());
      history.replace(SLUGS.login);
    }
    // handle internal server errors.
    if (error.response.status === 500) {
      toast.dark("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
    }
    // handle server ratelimits.
    if (error.response.status === 429) {
      toast.dark("You are being ratelimited.");
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

This is how I send requests from the frontend.
I use axios. I checked my cookies in the developer tools panel
and couldn't see the `sessionid` cookie there.

**EDIT 2**
[image]

Chrome devtools shows me the following error and is not
setting the sessionid cookie properly. Is this the reason maybe?

** Answer (SOLVED)**
setting the following variables in my settings.py file
made sure that chrome set the cookies correctly.

```py
# CORS configuration
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

Comment: You might not be maintaining a session from the client side. How do you make requests from the client?

Comment: with axios.. Sorry, I didn't know that I had to maintain a session from the client side. How would I do that?

Comment: I made my edits! Please check it out! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Axios send cookies in its requests automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically) (Set `withCredentials: true` in the config when calling `axios.create`)

Comment: Please check my edits @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355540/access-control-allow-origin-in-django-app-when-accessed-with-phonegap you need to provide cross origin headers

Comment: I've already set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` to True though.

Comment: Please show your `MIDDLEWARE` setting and the settings you have set for the cors headers.

Comment: thanks a lot! Your references helped me. I have solved this issue (I have mentioned how in my edits)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your correct `__call__` function

```
def __call__(self, request):
     print(request.session.get("MID_KEY"))
     if "MID_KEY" not in request.session:  
             next_id = str(uuid.uuid4())    
             request.session["MID_KEY"] = next_id.   
     return self.get_response(request)
```

The key shall be a string (constant) not a variable

Comment: I am sorry, but I want the session key to persist. That way, I can keep track of anonymous users. This does not do that.

Comment: It will do that as for every session the value of `MID_KEY` will be different but the key is the same and this is the idea behind key/value stores.